# Can't run valgrind massif with "page-as-heap" option

Tags: c, valgrind, massif

I am trying to run Valgrind in Ubuntu 14.04 with the following options:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes
```

But get the following error:

```
valgrind: Bad option: --page-as-heap=yes
```

This option is described in several places (and it is actually mentioned in valgrind's manual http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) to be used with massif.

How can I have this tool/option avaliable?

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have the latest version of valgrind.

Comment: I have version 3.10, the latest available for Ubuntu 14. According to the Valgrind website, the latest version is 3.11. Is "page-as-heap" only available in 3.11?

Comment: According to the valgrind release notes, it's available since 3.6 (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html). It might be unsupported, due to missing system support (or disabled at compile time). The option does need some runtime library.

Comment: @Leandros thanks - any idea where to start looking as to make this available?

Comment: Check the valgrind source, and their configure script, if you can enable the option somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. The correct command is:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes
```

Note the plural "pages".